# Using "this" with class name

Tags: java, android, this

I am doing Android programming and was learning about Intents, when I saw a constructor that, to my C# trained mind, seemed funky.  The call was:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
```

Both of the parameters are new to me.  How is there a static ".this" off of a Class Name?  Is this a Java thing or an Android thing?  I am assuming that it is the same as just saying "this", since I am in the context of `CurrentActivity`, but I don't get how the "this" can be called off of the Class name itself.  Also.  The ".class" looks like it is used for reflection, which I am familiar with in C#, but any insight into this would be welcomed as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Usually, you can use only `this`. But, sometimes `this` makes reference to an inner class... so, for example:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ticket_details_sell_ticket);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // it will be wrong to use only "this", because it would
        // reference the just created OnClickListener object
        Intent login = new Intent(ClassName.this, Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(login, LOGIN_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

Comment: I see.  So had I just said "this" in the new Intent in your example, it would be referring to the "this" of the OnClickListener class, but since I need to reference the outer class I need a way to signify that.

Comment: Right. `this` is always the innermost class.

Comment: And to answer the other part of the question: yes, it's a java thing

Comment: I was wondering why **MyClass.this** and not only **this** in when registering a listener! Thanks

Comment: Funny! Who knew that Java's `this` was so much like JavaScript's [`this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)? I guess that's what you get for not having first-class functions or lambdas :-)

Comment: Thanks @diego nunes; I'm disappointed it's inconsistent as that.

Answer (score 65):

One at a time:

The first construct is called a [qualified this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4). The purpose of the syntax is in the case where you are in an inner class (typically an anonymous inner class) and you want to reference the `this` of the outer class rather than the `this` of the (anonymous) inner class. The "qualified this" can only be used in a context where `this` would be ambiguous. The quote the JLS "It is a compile-time error if the expression occurs in a class or interface which is not an inner class of class T or T itself".

The second construct is called a `class literal` is the way to reference the Class object that represents that type. It can be used in any context.

Comment: It is worth noting, if this answer is still not clear enought, that it only works when there are an enclosed class and you are referencing an outer class. You simply cannot use "NotInTheStackOfEnclosings.this".

Comment: @DiegoNunes, that is true of the `qualified this` not of the `class literal`. I have expanded my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 14):

The syntax "Classname.this" is for inner classes. If you want to refer to the enclosing instance of type "Outerclass" then you do it as "Outerclass.this".

NextActivity.class is simply the Class object that describes class "NextActivity".

Answer (score 12):

`NextActivity.class` in java means `typeof(NextActivity)` in C#

Answer (score 9):

`ClassName.this` is used to reference the current instance of an outerclass from an inner class.

Comment: And certainly the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

```
<ClassName>.this
```

is used in nested classes to refer to the current instance of the enclosing class, since the `this' keyword refers to the nest class instance.

```
public class Siht {
    class NestedSiht {
        void demoThis() {
            System.err.println("this' is an instance of: " + 
                            this.getClass().getName());
            System.err.println("Siht.this' is an instance of: " +
                            Siht.this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

```
void demoThis() {
    new java.lang.Object() {
        void demoThis() {
            System.err.println("`this' is an instance of: " + 
                            this.getClass().getName());
            System.err.println("`Siht.this' is an instance of: " +
                            Siht.this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }.demoThis();
    new NestedSiht().demoThis();
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    new Siht().demoThis();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing only because when you use "**MainActivity.this**", it seems that you are referring to the class and not the object.
In reality when you use "this" you are always referring to the current object,
as the java se documentation states:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

> Within an instance method or a constructor, **this** is a reference **to the current objec**t — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

It's just syntactically peculiar.