# What different between class_name.this and this

Tags: java, android

I see some code use `class_name.this` as a parameter for its context, and sometimes use `this` directly in another demo code.  May I assume that `this` is a abbreviation of `class_name.this`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java) and [Java: Class.this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530256/java-class-this).

Answer (score 5):

We use `this` when if the class references can be type-casted to Context.  And when `this` object cann't be, then we use `ClassName.this` (BUT only if the class is child/ super child [*subclass*] of Context class. like Activity/ Services)

---

Read [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

---

Let me explain by example code (For example I am using `Activity` and `AsyncTask`)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.startActivity(intent); 
        // or 
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 
        // Both are same here. 
    }

    private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            this.startActivity(intent); // You can not do. Because "this" is the current object of AsyncTask not of Activity. 
            // So you can only use
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1.In Outer Class you directly use "this" reference
2.In Inner Class Or Abstract Class implementation Or Interface implementation use "classname.this" reference
```

Answer (score 1):

This is special syntax which allows to access outer class instance from an inner class. Consider this

```
class X {
    class Y {
        void y() {
            Object y = this;
            Object x = X.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClassName.this` allows you to refer to the external class even when inside a nested class.

For example `MyClickListener` is nested inside `MainAcvitiy`:

```
private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I have been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You need the reference to `MainActivity.this` because the current value of `this` is `MyClickListener` and you don't want to bother passing in a reference to the Activity here

Answer (score 0):

**this** is used to refer the current or live instance of class , but in cases where u have to use nested classes and nested class wants to access the member of outer class then its done by using class_name.this as it will make clear which class u are referring to.

refer this questions :-
[What is the difference between Class.this and this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java)