# Synchronized block in java

Tags: java, synchronized-block

I came across the code:

```
synchronized(Account.this)   
{}
```

where `Account` is a class.
Does `Account.this` mean any current instance of class Account?

Comment: Are you sure "Account" is a class and not a poorly named variable?

Comment: `Account.this` is referring to an instance of `Account`, in particular, "this" instance of the `Account`.  It may be that the reference is being made from within in an inner class where it's not possible to use `this` directly...

Comment: I imagine the code is in an anonymous or otherwise inner class and this the lock is on the outer class.

Comment: This explanation of the `Class.this` syntax might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5530293/2288659

Comment: This is a question not about multithreading but rather about Java syntax. I don't think the latter two tags are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is used inside of an inner class:
It means the `this` instance of the outer `Account` class.

Writing `this` by itself will return the instance of the inner class, not the outer class.

Answer (score 4):

This would probably be from an inner class of Account.

```
class Account {
  class InnerAccount {
    ...
    synchronized(Account.this) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: fix the "synchronized" spelling