# How to setVisibility within class extending FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-framelayout, circularreveal

I have a FAB class extending FrameLayout where I want to have a hide method which implements the reveal effect. Therefore I need to set the visibility to INVISIBLE:

```
public class FloatingActionButton extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    ...
    private void hide() {
        ...
            this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ...
        hideFabAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

But I get an error when trying to call `setVisibility()` on 'this' : "Cannot resolve method 'setVisibilty(int)'".

Comment: Sorry, forgot the error message. Made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` is located inside another class. It this case `FloatingActionButton.this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` will solve your issue.

You can find explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530293/436938).