# Concat a Title "GetTitle().Concat(GetTitle()));"

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, concatenation

today i try to do a example of a "Window" on Java. I try to Concat the Title but my "GetTitle()" don't work! Anyone can help me with this?

And why "public class MiVentana extends JFrame {" and "MiVentana Frame = new MiVentana("Titulo");" says warning?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MiVentana extends JFrame {

public MiVentana (String Titulo){
    this.setTitle(Titulo);
    this.setSize(300,400);
    this.setLocation(160,80);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.ConfigurarVentana();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void ConfigurarVentana(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton boton = new JButton ("OK");
    boton.addActionListener(new EscuchadorBoton());
    panel.add(boton);
    this.add(panel);
}

class EscuchadorBoton implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        this.setTitle(this.getTitle().concat(this.getTitle()));
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiVentana Frame = new MiVentana("Titulo");
    //frameTest.setVisible(true);
            }
    }
```

EDIT: I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 IDE Eclipse 3.8

Comment: What is the error and warning you are getting?

Comment: Try `MiVentana.this.getTitle()`

Comment: @JavaNut13 It gave me a error (With the SetTitle at the same line), i don't write this "When i press the button "OK" "Titulo" has to be concat with another "Titulo" so "TituloTitulo"

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ MiVentana says "The serializable class MiVentana does not declare a Static Final serialVersionUID field of type long".
And Frame "The value of the local variable frame is not used".

Comment: @Dash95 have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `this` inside the `ActionListener` refers to the `EscuchadorBoton` listener, not the instance of `MiVentana` - your `JFrame`.

Using `MiVentana.this` should refer to the window, not the listener and you'll be able to get and set the title with that.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530256/java-class-this) describes what is happening a bit better - basically you want `this` from the enclosing class, not the enclosed class.

Basically instead of doing this:

```
this.setTitle(this.getTitle().concat(this.getTitle()));
```

You need to do this:

```
MiVentana.this.setTitle(MiVentana.this.getTitle().concat(MiVentana.this.getTitle()));
```