# What is the scope of "this" when calling a method from an individual thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a small Java class to act a heartbeat for a project. The class is fairly simple. I have a public class called `HeartbeatServer.class` that contains to private classes which both implement `Runnable`.

The heartbeat and listener thread will both use the same `DatagramSocket` which I created outside of the scope of both thread classes and declared it volatile so both threads can access it.

My question is regarding my thread classes. In the thread classes if I call `HeartbeatServer.this.serverSocket` what is the scope of `this`? My concern is I don't want each thread to use a different version of `HeartbeatServer` since I have to bind the `DatagramSocket` to a specific IP address and port.

Is what I am doing correct to get the result I am looking for? I want both threads to have access to the same `DatagramSocket` that was created by the constructor of the `HeartbeatServer` class.

Here is my code.

```
public volatile DatagramSocket serverSocket;
private Map<String, InetSocketAddress> registeredClients = new HashMap<String, InetSocketAddress>();
public volatile Boolean running = true;

public HeartbeatServer() throws SocketException{

    serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);

}
```

** Other methods would go here **

```
// This is the thread that will send the heartbeats back to the client.
private class HeartbeatThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

       while (HeartbeatServer.this.running) {

           HeartbeatServer.this.sendData();

       }

    }

}

// This is the thread that will listen for clients connecting to the server.
private class ListenerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (HeartbeatServer.this.running) {

            HeartbeatServer.this.recieveData();

        }

    }

}
```

** NOTE **

My code is not done, so things might not make any sense in the current context.

Comment: HeartbeatServer.this will only work in the enclosed classes of HeartbeatServer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Class.this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530256/java-class-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `HeartbeatServer` to be unique you should make the `HeartbeatServer` **Singleton**. Please check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) for more details.

Simply

```
public class HeartbeatServer {
    private static HeartbeatServer heartbeatServer;

    // Disable object creation from other classes
    private HeartbeatServer () {
    }

    public static HeartbeatServer getInstance() {
          if(heartbeatServer == null)
              heartbeatServer = new HeartbeatServer();
          return heartbeatServer;        
    }
}
```

What you are doing is, your thread object is using the enclosing parent. Which is not recommended.

Comment: If I am accessing all of my methods through the singleton I created do I need to declare my socket and running variables as volatile?

Comment: If you are frequently writing the values from multiple threads to the variable in singleton then do that. If its a read only no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the `HeartBeatServer` instance you get is the right one,  you could add a constructor to the internal runnables, along the lines of

```
private class HeartbeatThread implements Runnable {

  private HeartbeatServer server;

  HeartBeatThread(HeartbeatServer theServer) {
    this.server = theServer;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
     while (server.running) {
       server.sendData();
     }
  }

}
```