# Nested class: `OuterClass.this.someAttribute`?

Tags: java, mybatis, inner-classes

Hi I'm reading myBatis' source code and my problem is that I don't understand the line `SqlSessionManager.this.localSqlSession.get()`. What's the meaning of `SqlSessionManager.this`?

My trying: If I remember it correctly When create a nested class say `A.B nestedObjectB = new A.B();` It actually create an object `A.B` and an anonymous object `A` for it. So I guess `SqlSessionManager.this` is analogous to the object `A` here?

(In `SqlSessionManager.java`)

```
private class SqlSessionInterceptor implements InvocationHandler {
    public SqlSessionInterceptor() {
        // Prevent Synthetic Access
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
      final SqlSession sqlSession = SqlSessionManager.this.localSqlSession.get(); // *
      if (sqlSession != null) {
        try {
          return method.invoke(sqlSession, args);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
          throw ExceptionUtil.unwrapThrowable(t);
        }
      } else {
        try (SqlSession autoSqlSession = openSession()) {
          try {
            final Object result = method.invoke(autoSqlSession, args);
            autoSqlSession.commit();
            return result;
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            autoSqlSession.rollback();
            throw ExceptionUtil.unwrapThrowable(t);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Class.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530256/java-class-this)

Comment: @AdwaitKumar: So why it is used here? If SqlSessionInterceptor doesn't has attribute `localSqlSession`? Why not just write `locatSqlSession.get()`?

Comment: Cause it wants to ensure that the outer class `localSqlSession` is referred, if you used this it would refer to the object of `SqlSessionInterceptor` which doesn't have a `localSqlSession`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlSessionManager.this` refers to the outer class, if you just used `this` it would refer to `SqlSessionInterceptor` which doesn't have a `localSqlSession`.

If you used just `localSqlSession` it would refer to the immediate outer class. If there was another outerClass between `SqlSessionManager` and `SqlSessionInterceptor`, then it would refer to that class instead of `SqlSessionManager`. Adding `SqlSessionManager.this` explicitly declares to use the one present in  `SqlSessionManager`

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816462/ , https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530293

EDIT :

Referring to https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionManager.java#L347, it seems this is being done only for readability.

Comment: So `localSqlSession.get()` implicitly means `SqlSessionManager.this.localSqlSession.get()`? The former one get no error.

Comment: Edited my answer.