# What is the Java translation to this@NameOfTheClass::open from Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, translate

I'm working on a Java project, having as reference a Kotlin project. This code uses this expression, which I would guess comes from functional programming:

```
this@MarkdownWorkspace::open
```

This is used in a constructor's parameter, which needs a *"java.util.function.Consumer"* object.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java equivalent of `this@MarkdownWorkspace::open` would be `MarkdownWorkspace.this::open`

Comment: Thank you so much @pavi2410 , is there any chance you can explain me what it does?

Comment: @LunaM here's a very good answer which explains the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530293/7595401