# Why is the view size not changing dynamically in my app?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the size of `MyView` by pressing a button.

The initial size of `MyView` is 400 * 400, every time I press button `b1`, `w` adds 100. I suppose the view size should change, but it remains 400 * 400. However, if I change the size of the button `b2` in the `ClickListener`, (add line a and line b), both the size of `b2` and `MyView` change size. I don't know how this happens. If I just want to change the size of `MyView` dynamically, what should I do?

Relevant code:

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

Button b1;
Button b2;
Context sContext;
public static int i = 0;
private int w = 400;
private int h = 400;
private int w2 = 100;
private int h2 = 100;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sContext = context;
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sContext = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    b1 = new Button(sContext);
    b2 = new Button(sContext);
    addView(b1);
    addView(b2);
    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    b2.setX(500);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (MyView.this.getLayoutParams() == null) {
                MyView.this.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
            } else {
                MyView.this.getLayoutParams().width = w;
                MyView.this.getLayoutParams().height = h;
            }

                MyView.this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


            //b2.setWidth(w2);          line a
            //b2.setHeight(h2);         line b

            //MyView.this.invalidate();
            w += 100;
            w2 += 20;
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    test();
}

private void test() {
    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    b2.setX(200.0f);
    Toast.makeText(sContext, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ++i;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A couple of odd things I noticed

1) `//MyView.this.invalidate()` is commented out.  You need to call either `invalidate()` or `revalidate()` when you change your layout.

2) I'm not sure why you're using `MyView.this` - try using just `this`.  The only time I've seen Classname.this is when you're in an inner class and need to get to the outer one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080868/java-classname-this)).  MyView is not an inner class.

3) `//super.onDraw(canvas)` is commented out.  With java drawing/painting overrides you almost always want to call super to make sure children and parent containers get the message to redraw as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
private void init() {
    b1 = new Button(sContext);
    b2 = new Button(sContext);
    addView(b1);
    addView(b2);
    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    b2.setX(500);
    LayoutParams lp =getLayoutParams();
    if(lp==null){
       lp=new LayoutParams(w,h);
       setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    lp.height=h;
    lp.width=w;
    requestLayout();

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            MyView.this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
             w += 100;
            getLayoutParams().width=w;
            requestLayout();
    }

});
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That's the answer, I have to call requestLayout(). Thank you very much!