# Why can't I refer enclosing class's non-static var from its inner class's non-static method?

Tags: java, static, nested, this

In my awareness, non-static method will be assigned "this" variables for its class obj & all enclosing classes.

```
public class TestNested {

int a=4;

public static class a{

    int a=5;

    static int c=10;

    class b{

        int a=6;

        void aaa(){

            int a=7;

            TestNested t=new TestNested();

            System.out.println(this.a);

            System.out.println(b.this.a);

            System.out.println(TestNested.a.b.this.a);

            System.out.println(TestNested.a.this.a);

            System.out.println(a.this.a);

            System.out.println(t.a);

            System.out.println(TestNested.this.a);

        }
    }
}

void r(){

    TestNested t=new TestNested();

    TestNested.a a=new TestNested.a();

    a.b b=a.new b();

    b.aaa();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestNested t=new TestNested();

    t.r();
}
}
```

in this case the final statement of `void aaa()` is `System.out.println(TestNested.this.a);` will be sentenced to cause compilation error with the reason :**'com.xxx.TestNested.this' cannot be referenced from static context**, that's really confusing me because the `this` var that points to `TestNested` should be the non-static hidden var of the method itself,then why it can't use its own var?

Or if my awareness is wrong that each `that` var is assigned in each class enclosed from the method's class, but the `void aaa()` isn't a static method which means it can reference non-static var rite? or even the method isn't static, but if one of its enclosing class is static, it'll be automatically recognized as static member?

Comment: Please rename your class `a` in CamelCase. It is very hard to explain things if you're using the same names for classes, variables and fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your nested class `a` is **not** an inner class of `TestNested`. It is a **static** nested class, meaning that it is not linked to a particular instance of `TestNested`.

> *Note: an **inner** class is a **non-static** nested class.*

What instance of `TestNested` would you expect your expression `TestNested.this` to refer to?

You can see, by the way, that you're not referring to your variable `t` here:

```
TestNested.a a=new TestNested.a();
```

Which points out that the object `a` is not linked to `t` at all.

---

In my above answer, I assumed it was clear to you what you were doing with `this`. It appears it is not the case, according to your comments, so I'm going to try and clarify it here.

First of all, `this` always refers to an object: an instance of a class.

Let's assume we're in the context of a non-static method in the class `b`. Because the method is non-static, the code will be executed relatively to a particular instance of `b`. I take the shortcut to refer to this particular instance as "the instance of `b` you're in".

Since `b` is an inner class of `a`, no instance of `b` can exist outside an instance of `a`. This means the instance of `b` you're in is enclosed in an instance of `a`. I take the shortcut to refer to this particular instance as "the instance of `a` you're in" (Technically, you're in a `b` which is in an `a`).

So, in this context of a non-static method of `b`:

- `this` refers to the instance of the `b` you're in. It is the standard use of this keyword.
- `b.this`, `a.b.this` or `TestNested.a.b.this` are the same as `this` here, the difference is only that you qualify more precisely the class `b`.
- `a.this` or `TestNested.a.this` both refer to the instance of `a` you're in (`TestNested.a` is just a more precise qualification for `a`). This `a` object exists because `b` is an inner class of `a`, which means that every instance of `b` is linked to an instance of `a`. This is the only way to refer to the instance of `a`.
- `TestNested.this` would refer to the instance of `TestNested` you're in. But **you're not in any instance of `TestNested`**, so it does not mean anything, hence the compile error. You're in an instance of `b`, which is within an instance of `a` (because `b` is an inner class of `a`). The instance of `a` exists by itself because `a` is a static nested class of `TestNested`, so it is not linked to an instance of `TestNested`.

Comment: Hi, thx so much for ur explaining, but I still have a question about it,
I'm fully aware that the static nested class is actually a top-level class when u need to use it,
but if it's really in the top-level of class hierarchy, then why can we still use `TestNested.a.b.this.a` to refer the `static class a` & its members?

Comment: This is just a matter of namespace. `TestNested.a.b.this` just refers to the instance of `TestNested.a.b` you're in. You could have used simply `this` and it would have had the same effect in this case.

Comment: Thx so much @Joffrey , so can I make the conclusion as the following:

In the aspect of code structure, `TestNested` is still the the enclosing class of `a`, but for usage, it's actually the top-leveled class of `b`?

I think it's actually a design bug, cuz if `a` is seen as top-level, then we should can't refer `a` & `b` through `TestNested`? Doesn't make any sense!!

Comment: @KiahStarck I don't understand what you mean by *"it's actually the top-leveled class of* `b` *"* . `a` is a static nested class of `TestNested` (not linked to a particular instance of it), and `b` is an inner class of `a`. So the hierarchy is respected, `a` is not *"seen as top-level"*.

Comment: @KiahStarck Could you please explain what exactly does not make sense? I find that everything is really logical here. I don't get where you see a design "bug".

Comment: @KiahStarck My apologies, I didn't expect you to interpret an aggressive tone in my comment, I wasn't at all ;-) I just don't understand what you don't understand here, and I was merely asking for clarification. And your last comment still didn't help. Did you mean `TestNested`? Yes you can refer to `a` in `TestNested`, but what is wrong with that?

Comment: sry man that's a unfinished comment which was wrongly sent, thx so much again for ur help!!

Comment: calm down man

I rethink abt it, first let me clean one thing that ur "linked to `TestNested` " means my `this` assigned to non-static method rite?

If it's rite, can I think this as: static nested class is also an static member of  `TestNested`, so it & its member(even a non-static method of its nested class) can't be assigned "this", so my case happens, rite? And this is the  same reason of ur " static nested cannot be linked to `TestNested` rite?

Comment: @KiahStarck I just realized that you were not really comfortable with the expression `Something.this`. `this` is not a field, it is just a keyword referring to the object you're in, or to be more precise, the non-static context of the code that calls it. I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`TestNested.a` <-- references a static variable of a static class

`this.a` <-- references an instance variable of an object

`TestNested.this` <-- tries to reference an object from a static context, but "this" does not exist in a static context.

You can reference static content from non-static, but not vice-versa.

Comment: sry mate, really don't understand these two parts:
**TestNested.a is static class + static variable**
**this.a is non-static + static variable**

and in this part **TestNested.this tries to reference non-static content (this) from static context.** , that's also my question point which was asking that is `void aaa` also a static method bcuz it's enclosing is static even it's not declared as static method?

Comment: *TestNested.this <-- tries to reference an object from a static context, but "this" does not exist in a static context.* -- this is not always true. `ClassName.this` is also a syntax used in an inner class to refer to its enclosing object. This is exactly what confuses the OP here, because we are currently in a static nested class, and not in an inner class. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080868/using-this-with-class-name

Comment: @sinclair  thx so much, I fully understand now, actually I thought abt it in my discussion with Joffrey above lol! I think that's the reason bcuz static nested class is also an static member to `TestNested`, so it & its members(even a non-static method of one of its nested class) won't be assigned `this` var for its enclosing, just like the situation of the normal class(no nested class situation), static method won't have `this` var for its located class's members, is that what u mean? thx!!

Comment: @Joffrey I think sinclair's answer is what I wanna say to u above lol, but seems like it's not always true according to you, but we can't reference `TestNested` from `a`'s inner by `this` var still?btw what's OP u said? thx!

Comment: @KiahStarck OP means Original Post(er), that's you ;-) I'll update my answer to clarify the usage of `this`.