# Can't understand path dependent type

Tags: scala

For a class C, you can use the familiar `this` inside the body to refer to the current instance, but `this` is actually a shorthand for C.this in Scala:

```
class C {
   var x = "1"
   def setX1(x:String) = this.x = x
   def setX2(x:String) = C.this.x = x
}
```

I just can't understand `C.this`, C is a class, I can't understand why we use dot between `C` and `this` as shown in `C.this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't understand why we use dot between C and this as shown in
>   C.this

Using the class name before `this` is called a [Qualified this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) in Java (see [Using "this" with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080868/using-this-with-class-name)) and is similar in Scala. You use it when you want to reference an outer class from an inner class. Let's assume for example that you had a method declaration in your `C` class where you wanted to call `this` and mean "the this reference of `C`:

```
class C {
  val func = new Function0[Unit] {
    override def apply(): Unit = println(this.getClass) 
  }
}

new C().func()
```

Yields:

```
class A$A150$A$A150$C$$anon$1
```

You see the `anon$1` at the end of the `getClass` name? It's because inside the function instance this `this` is actually of the function class. But, we actually wanted to reference the `this` type of `C` instead. For that, you do:

```
class C {
  val func = new Function0[Unit] {
    override def apply(): Unit = println(C.this.getClass)
  }
}

new C().func()
```

Yields:

```
class A$A152$A$A152$C
```

Notice the `C` at the end instead of `anon$1`.