# What is ClassName.this?

Tags: java, android

I know `this` refers to the current object. I am little confused about `this.ClassName` and `ClassName.this` when creating `Intent`.

Comment: What is ClassName?

Comment: Possibly related to `ClassName.this`: [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Comment: public class LoginPage{}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I am little confused about `this.ClassName` and `ClassName.this` when creating Intent.

The `Classname.this` syntax is used to refer to an outer class instance when you are using nested classes; see [Using "this" with class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080868/using-this-with-class-name) for more details.

However `this.Classname` is a compilation error ... unless you have declared an instance (or static) field with the name `Classname`.  (That would be a daft thing to do, as well as being an egregious style violation.)

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, AcitivityName.class);
```

The first argument is just the context so when you write for ex. Main.this you are just referring to the context of that activity.

The second argument is the a Activity you want to start or whatever...

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming ClassName is just filling in for the current class's name. ClassName.this is exactly the same as simply writing this. So if a class had a variable called foo you could reference it from that class using ClassName.this.foo the same way you could with this.foo.

this.ClassName is not valid java as far as I know.